# if user-defined type is null then select whole table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a user-defined type as below

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[HaveItemUdt] AS TABLE(
    [Defindex] [int] NULL
)
```

In my stored proc

```
@HaveItemList AS HaveItemUdt READONLY

SELECT * FROM tbl_something WHERE itemID IN (SELECT itemID FROM @HaveItemList)
```

When the @HaveItemList is empty, i want to select the whole table like this

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_something WHERE itemID IN (SELECT itemID FROM tbl_something )
```

I try this but doesn't work

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_something WHERE itemID IN (SELECT itemID FROM @HaveItemList) OR @HaveItemList IS NULL
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `not exists`.

```
select *
from tbl_something
where ( not exists(select 1 from @HaveItemList ) 
        or itemID in (select Defindex from @HaveItemList ))
```

the idea is that the first part will return true if `@HaveItemList` is empty and so the following `IN` clause is 'ignored'

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @HaveItemList int
SET @HaveItemList = 5

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_something WHERE itemID IN (SELECT itemID FROM '

SELECT @sql = @sql + 
 CASE 
    WHEN @HaveItemList IS NULL THEN ' TblSomething)'
    ELSE '' + CAST(@HaveItemList AS varchar) + ')'
END

 PRINT @sql
 -- EXEC sp_executesql @sql -- Uncomment to execute the generated statement
```

If you comment the second line where the value for @HaveItemList is set, it'll evaluate to NULL, and the select will be done on the table.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question as you changed the type of `@HaveItemList`. Also testing for whether the id is in the same table it came from sounds rather inefficient.

Comment: @TI I edited the post and changed it to int. Better?